# Vuetify Datepicker format

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify Datepicker:

```
<v-menu
    v-model="menu1"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    max-width="290"
>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-text-field
        v-model="editedItem.Eintrittsdatum"
        clearable
        color="primary"
        label="Eintrittsdatum"
        v-on="on"
    ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
        v-model="editedItem.Eintrittsdatum"
        @change="menu1 = false"
        locale="de"
    ></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

The return value is the normally formatted date (yyyy-mm-dd). This is also the data I would like to save in the v-model (and eventually inside the data object). However, just for the eye-candy I would like to display the value of the text-field with a different format.

I have created a little function:

```
formatDate(date) {
    return date ? moment(date).format("L") : "";
}
```

Is there a way to call this function to overwrite the displayed value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the formatDate to a computed, and utilize your already defined `editedItem.Eintrittsdatum`, which is used in the `v-model` of your actual `v-date-picker`

In your script tag:

```
computed: {
  formatDate() {
    return this.editedItem.Eintrittsdatum
      ? moment(this.editedItem.Eintrittsdatum).format("L")
      : "";
  }
}
```

Changed `v-text-field`

```
<v-text-field
    :value="formatDate"
    clearable
    color="primary"
    label="Eintrittsdatum"
    v-on="on"
></v-text-field>
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-y7ziz